# How do I take a picture of what fits inside a square in android?

Tags: android, image, crop, android-screen-support

I have to make my app capable of taking pictures of *only* whatever it fits a squared frame that is superimposed on the preview.

The idea is: the client wants the app to send pictures of 600x600px tops. To avoid cropping important parts of the picture, he decided to put this superimposed squared frame (similar to the one in QR-reading apps) and to crop out everything out of said frame.

To do this I need two things.
1) How do I set the frame dimensions for multiple screens while getting the output within the required dimensions? 
2) Once the frame is up and running... how do I crop out the rest of the picture?

Thanks in advance.

Update

What I want to do is something similar to what is explained here http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/
Thing is:

- This how-to *checks if there's an image-cropper app installed*, it
  doesn't do the cropping by itself (or so I understand, maybe I'm
  wrong?).
- The frame seems to be 200x200... px? dp? Would that frame take up the
  same portion of screen on xhdpi screens that on ldpi screens?
- What's the size of the resulting image? Can I decide it somehow?

Comment: I think this should be doable with OpenGL ES 2.0 SurafaceTexture preview at least. Using it you can crop the visible preview however you decide to on your GLSL shaders. Then for saving you can simply resize the area you want to within picture taken callback.